# What to use to dispaly formatted text in Xamarin IOS?

Tags: c#, uiview, xamarin.ios

I want to display a formatted text in Xamarin IOS, c#. That means a text with special font and also links, like in the picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BSpH.jpg

I want to use just one TextView, or something else, but the lines must be continoulosly in the control.

Which controls, or methods of TextView should I use?

Comment: It sounds like what you're trying to do is have a dynamic text block that supports tags (like HTML).  I don't think that's possible in a single TextView.  You'd have to write something custom for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can style text in iOS with [NSAttributedString](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/text_field/style_text/)

Answer (score 0):

You want to used some form of attributed string. You can use either `NSAttributedString` or `NSMutableAttributedString`. There may be some other forms. The mutable strings allow you to change the contents and style after creation and have different styles along the length of the string (for example "Hello World" could have "Hello" be in black and "World" be in red). I'm going to assume you're going to want to use a NSMutableString considering you will be using multiple different styles in one line.

Here's a quick example on how to use it.

```
NSDictionary format = new NSDictionary (
                UIStringAttributeKey.Font, UIFont.FromName ("FontName", 20),
                UIStringAttributeKey.ForegroundColor, UIColor.Black
            );

NSMutableAttributedString nsString = new NSMutableAttributedString("String", format);

UILabel label = new UILabel();
label.AttributedText = nsString;
```

Obviously for your application, you're going to have to delve into the Xamarin NSMustableString docs (https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSMutableAttributedString/) in order to fully customize it to your liking, but I think I've given you a decent jumpstart.

Answer (score 0):

NSAttributedString definitely works.
To use custom fonts follow [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40126454/1101710).