# Why are my custom fonts not working in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, fonts, xamarin.ios

Boy I'm stuck. I think I've looked at every guide online for this and cannot get it to work. Here are the steps I've done:

1. I've added this directory of custom fonts to my Xamarin.iOS project
   under Resources/Fonts.
2. I've set their buildactions all as
   BundledResources.
3. I've set for them to always copy to the build
   directory.
4. I've added their names to Info.Plist like so:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
      <string>BentonSans-Regular.otf</string>
      <string>BentonSans-Black.otf</string>
      <string>BentonSans-Bold.otf</string>
      <string>BentonSans-Book.otf</string>
      <string>BentonSans-CompMediumRegular.otf</string>
      <string>BentonSans-Medium.otf</string>
    </array>
```

5. I try setting the font like so:

   `button.Font = UIFont.FromName("BentonSansComp-Medium", 16);`

**Please note** doing it this way, my app runs, but the fonts don't seem to take any effect. I have tried putting `Fonts/` in front of the fonts in info.plist, but this causes an exception where the referenced font is null in the code.

I really can't work out what I'm missing here. The fonts just don't seem to apply. I used SushiHangover's [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36968636/812013) to ensure that my fonts are registered:

```
2021-05-11 16:03:01.168473+0100 MyProject[54240:1851117]  * BentonSans Black
2021-05-11 16:03:01.169049+0100 MyProject[54240:1851117]  *-- BentonSans-Black
2021-05-11 16:03:01.169423+0100 MyProject[54240:1851117]  * BentonSans Bold
2021-05-11 16:03:01.169862+0100 MyProject[54240:1851117]  *-- BentonSans-Bold
2021-05-11 16:03:01.170201+0100 MyProject[54240:1851117]  * BentonSans Book
2021-05-11 16:03:01.170743+0100 MyProject[54240:1851117]  *-- BentonSans-Book
2021-05-11 16:03:01.171092+0100 MyProject[54240:1851117]  * BentonSans Comp Medium
2021-05-11 16:03:01.171826+0100 MyProject[54240:1851117]  *-- BentonSansComp-Medium
2021-05-11 16:03:01.172315+0100 MyProject[54240:1851117]  * BentonSans Medium
2021-05-11 16:03:01.173718+0100 MyProject[54240:1851117]  *-- BentonSans-Medium
2021-05-11 16:03:01.174237+0100 MyProject[54240:1851117]  * BentonSans Regular
2021-05-11 16:03:01.175211+0100 MyProject[54240:1851117]  *-- BentonSans-Regular
```

This showed me that I was getting the name wrong for BentonSansComp-Medium which did fix a runtime error earlier. But it didn't make the font apply.

Answer (score 0):

You used string "BentonSansComp-Medium" as the parameter of method "UIFont.FromName", but it doesn't exist in your plist.

I just followed the blog [Using custom Fonts in Xamarin.iOS](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/custom-fonts-in-ios/), and test with .ttf and .otf. Everything works fine.

Folder in Solution Explorer:

[image]

Here is my info.plist. (Build Action: BundleResource, Copy to Output Directory: Copy always)

[image]

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
  <string>Fonts/MyFonts/Winter.otf</string>
  <string>Fonts/MyFonts/Goodest.ttf</string>
</array>
```

test code:

```
var lab1 = new UILabel(new RectangleF(0, 100, 300, 40));
lab1.Text = "This is some sample text";
lab1.Font = UIFont.FromName("Winter", 20f);
this.Add(lab1);
```